# Child state not updated while child props updated

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have a `Parent` component which generates (and renders) a list of `Child` components like this:

```
const Parent= ({ user }) => {

const [state, setState] = useState ({selectedGames: null
                                     currentGroup: null})

...

  let allGames = state.selectedGames ? state.selectedGames.map(g => <Child
        game={g} user={user} disabled={state.currentGroup.isLocked && !user.admin} />) : null

...

return ( <div> {allGames} </div>)

}
```

The `Child` component is also a stateful component, where the state (`displayInfo`) is only used to handle a toggle behaviour (hide/display extra data):

```
 const Child = ({ game, user, disabled = false }) => {


     const [displayInfo, setDisplayInfo] = useState(false)
    
        const toggleDisplayInfo = () =>
        {
            const currentState = displayInfo
    
            setDisplayInfo(!currentState)
        }

...
    
      <p className='control is-pulled-right'>
              <button class={displayInfo ? "button is-info is-light" : "button is-info"} onClick = {toggleDisplayInfo}>
                    <span className='icon'>
                         <BsFillInfoSquareFill />
                    </span>
                          
              </button>
      </p>

      ...

      return ({displayInfo ? <p> Extra data displayed </p> : null})

}
```

When `state.selectedGames` is modified (for example when a user interacts with the `Parent` component through a `select`), `state.selectedGames` is correctly updated **BUT** the **state** of the i-th `Child` component stay in its previous state. As an example, let's say:

- I clicked the button from the **i-th** `Child` component thus displaying `"Extra data displayed"` for this `i-th` `Child` only
- I interact with the `Parent` component thus modifying `state.selectedGames` (no common element between current and previous `state.selectedGames`)

I can see that all `Child` have been correctly updated according to their new props (`game`, `user`, `disable`) but the `i-th` `Child` still has its `displayInfo` set to `true` (its state has thus not been reset contrary to what I would have (naively) expected) thus displaying `"Extra data displayed"`.

**EDIT:**

After reading several SO topics on similar subjects, it appears using a `key` prop could solves this (note that each `game` passed to the `Child` component through the `game` props has its own unique ID). I have also read that such a `key` prop is not directly expose so I'm a bit lost...

Does passing an extra `key` prop with `key={g.ID}` to the `Child` component would force a re-rendering?

Comment: That is the nornal behaviour. To reset the local state you need to either have a specific condition that does that in the component, or cause the component to unmount/remount by giving it a diffrerent `key`. An alternative is to store the `displayInfo` flag in the `selectedGames` array as well, and pass it as a prop to the `Child`.

Comment: Thus, adding `key={g.ID}` where g.ID is unique, in `Child` prop, such as added in my original post, should so it?

Comment: Nope, since it is the same `id` for the same element, it would not cause an unmount.

Comment: Yes but if there is no common `g` (thus no common `id`) in `state.selectedGames` before and after modification that should do the trick, right?